# How is the parity check matrix for BCH is calculated?

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory

In BCH generator matrix is calculated by taking lcm of minimal polynomials. For example generator polynomial for GF(32) is following

$   m1(x) = x^5 + x^2 + 1$

$ m3(x) = x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$

$m5(x) = x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$

$g(x) =  x^{15} + x^{11} + x^{10} + x^9 + x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 $

My question is how can i write generator polynomial to generator matrix?

How can i calculate parity check matrix for BCH?

Comment: Why do you need the generator matrix? To make it more clear, also add the minimal polynomials if you know them.

Comment: @msm i added the minimal polynomials

Comment: Well, do you know the length and dimension of your code? There is a standard way of getting *a* generator matrix from the generator polynomial. So if you know those parameters and the method, what is the problem?

Comment: You can write the parity-check matrix for a primitive element  $\alpha$ in $GF(32)$ as $$H=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 &\cdots \\ 
1 & \alpha^3 & \alpha^6 &\cdots \\ 
1 & \alpha^5 & \alpha^{10} &\cdots  
\end{bmatrix}$$ then substitute the corresponding 5-tuple to find the binary matrix.

Comment: $ \alpha : m1(x)=x^5+x^2+1  $ how can i write it in matrix form? @msm

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen length is 31 bits and don't know how to calculate dimension

Comment: @msm i calculated $\alpha ,\alpha ^{1} ...\alpha ^{30}$ they are in 5-tuple form $00010, 00100,..,10010$ how do i write it

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen how can i write above generator polynomial in matrix form

Comment: Write them as column vectors in the matrix $H$. You should have considered that $\alpha^{31}=1$.